# Why does not Dictionary adopt MutableCollectionType protocol?

Tags: swift, dictionary

While implementing a custom collection type (and therefore making it to adhere to `CollectionType` protocol) I came to wonder why `MutableCollectionType` is not adopted by `Dictionary` type?

From the documentation for `MutableCollectionType`:

> A collection that supports subscript assignment.
>
> For any instance a of a type conforming to MutableCollectionType, :
>
> ```
> a[i] = x
> let y = a[i]
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> a[i] = x
> ```
>
> let y = x

Therefore, it would seem "logical" that Dictionary also adopts this protocol.  However, after checking out header files as well as docs, it seems that only `Array` and related types do that.

What's so special about `MutableCollectionType`, or about `Dictionary`, or both for that matter?  Should my dictionary-like custom collection type also avoid adopting `MutableCollectionType` for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the headers:

> Whereas an arbitrary *sequence* may be consumed as it is traversed, a *collection* is multi-pass: any element may be revisited merely by saving its index.

That makes no sense for a dictionary, as a dictionary is unordered. Just because the entry keyed by "howdy" is at index 2 right now does not mean it will be at index 2 one minute from now. In particular, it makes no sense to say "insert this key *at index 2*" - it is the keys and the internal hashing that provide the order. The indexes have no persistent life of their own. Thus, it is a collection (it has indexes), but not a mutable collection (you can't write into it by index).

Comment: The excerpt you provide is from the description of `CollectionType` which **is** adopted by `Dictionary`.  My question is about `MutableCollectionType`.

Comment: True but think about else I say. The docs quotation is just warm-up.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I start to get it now.  The subtle difference is in `key` vs. `index`, which are not the same for `Dictionary`.  Mutability means being able to change the value at an `index`, but `Dictionary` does not allow that.  It only allows changes at a given `key`.

Answer (score 2):

A glance through the [protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_MutableCollectionType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/MutableCollectionType/s:FeRq_Ss21MutableCollectionTypeqq_Ss16MutableIndexable5IndexSs21RandomAccessIndexTypeqqq_Ss14CollectionType9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementSs10Comparable_SsS_9partitionuRq_S_qq_S0_5IndexS1_qqq_S2_9GeneratorS3_7ElementS4__FRq_FGVSs5Rangeqq_S0_5Index_qq_S0_5Index) describes it as having methods like `sort` and `partition`. It also has an internal type call `SubSequence`. These are meaningless with dictionaries. There are no order within a dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

To understand the declaration of `MutableCollectionType` protocol, you first need to know a concept called subscript.

When you write “`let y = dic[key]`”, Swift is calling a method called subscript getter:

```
subscript (key: Key) -> Value? { get }
```

And when you write “`dic[key] = x`”, Swift is calling a method called subscript setter:

```
subscript (key: Key) -> Value? { set }
```

Now let's look at the `MutableCollectionType` protocol. `Dictionary` does not conform to `MutableCollectionType`. because the required methods of this protocol is not implemented in `Dictionary`.

One of the required method is

```
public subscript (position: Self.Index) -> Self.Generator.Element { get set }
```

This subscript method is not the same as the above two we use every day. The type of `position` is `Self.Index`, which is `DictionaryIndex<Key, Value>` for `Dictionary` type. And the return type `Self.Generator.Element` is `(Key, Value)`. I think This index type `DictionaryIndex` is something related to the hash table implementation, which can be used to directly refer to an hash table element. When you use the setter of the subscript you will write something like

```
dic[index] = (key, value)
```

It certainly makes no sense to replace a hash map element with another key value pair. This subscript setter is never implemented by `Dictionary`, so it does not conform to `MutableCollectionType` protocol.

Comment: I know that `Dictionary` does not adopt `MutableCollectionType` protocol.  My question was exactly about that.  That is, why does it not do so.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov Didn't I describe it clearly? It does not adopt the protocol because the required method of that protocol is not implemented.