# Dictionary Changes Index Positions with .keys -- Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently retrieving data from a firebase database, and storing the data in a dictionary. When I try to list the keys in the dictionary like this: `snapDict?.keys` the indexes of the elements aren't the same as how they are in the database.

```
Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot.childrenCount)
            let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
            print(snapshot.value!)
            let names = snapDict?.keys
            print(names!)
            for id in names! {
                self.searchNames(id: id)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
```

This is what the elements that *will* be in the dictionary look like in the database: [image]

So, you would think when they are put into the dictionary they would be printed as `-LJRUC8n........-LOF6JUdm-onVuaq-zij`?

```
snapDict?.keys
```

prints:

```
["-LOBSAv_l5_x1xnKwx3_", "-LJRUC8nPF3Vg-DDGiYQ", "-LOBLXpTs39yLZo6EnHl", "-LOF6JUdm-onVuaq-zij", "-LODhXPQi8G7MX1bSfeb", "-LJaUiEnGOcBjKsTWSCS", "-LOBLZzrLAlzkhoidnKf"]
```

I can't figure out the order/pattern here. Alphabetical? Any ideas why the order turns out this way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32934790/341994

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys in a dictionary are by definition unordered. So when you convert the snapshot to a dictionary, any information on the order of the nodes is lost.

On top of that, you don't specify an order before reading the data.

To fix both:

```
Database.database().reference()
  .child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts")
  .queryOrderedByKey()
  .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
      print(snapshot.childrenCount)
      for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
          print(child.value)     
      }
  })
```